# Lebesgue integral of non-invertable function

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Edit: This questions has been sufficiently answered

I have a function which is too complicated to integrate using Riemann integration so I am trying to evaluate it with Lebesgue integration. I have seen how to integrate simple functions like $f(x)=x^2$ with Lebesgue integration but this involves using $f^{-1}(x)$.

The function I have does not have a closed form for its inverse. In fact the function I am considering is

$f(x)= \frac{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt{ax^{\frac{2}{3}}-1}}e^{(1-bx^{\frac{2}{3}}-cx^2)}$

Do I have any hopes of utilising Lebesgue integration to integrate this over all values of x which have real valued f(x)? The values of x where f(x) is real are $(a^{\frac{3}{2}},\infty)$

Comment: Lebesgue integration doesn't make things less complicated. Its main benefit in a computational sense is that more functions are integrable. Those functions that were not Riemann integrable in the first place are usually pretty pathological, and your function doesn't qualify as it is continuous, or at most discontinuous at finitely many points.

Comment: I would say in most of the time of computing the value of integral, I can only use the technique for Riemann integral. Lebesgue integration only helps in make more function integrable and easy to handle with some convergence theorems.